# How to escape a hash (#) character in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

<s>I have a password field where a user can enter a password consisting of special characters. When there is a hash in the string, it takes a substring of all the previous characters before the hash, and discards the rest. No other keyboard special character causes this. An example is below:</s>

An example password: 123456#abc123

`$("#newPassword").val() // Returns the string "123456"`

How should I escape the string so that the hash character does interfere with the string?

**UPDATE:** Issue is in my query string, not the jQuery itself.

Comment: _"`$("#newPassword").val()` // Returns the string "123456""_ - [No, it doesn't](http://jsfiddle.net/xs6tmc7w/1/). Please add a [mcve] which shows the actual problem.

Comment: A case where that would be if you did a parseInt on the value, which would discard all the numbers after the first NaN. Let's see some more code, please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your script is correct, you don't need any escape for the string

```js
var pass = $("#newPassword").val();
$('#result').text(pass);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="newPassword" type="password" value="123456#abc123">
<div id="result"></div>
```

Comment: How can the comment "it works" be an answer? And why would this be accepted? O.o

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/277923/are-your-code-works-fine-for-me-answers-acceptable  ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯